# How to crop subsection of 2D array?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array declared as `new byte[w, h]`. I want to crop out a sub-section of this array given coordinates `(x1,y1)`-`(x2,y2)`. What's the quickest way to do this? Are there any methods for "slicing" 2D arrays?

Comment: Can a slice wrap around the array edges.  i.e.  Is (2,2) => (1,2) valid?

Comment: @steaks: No. The cropped region will always be within the original byte array. Worst case is its the exact same size: (0,0) to (w-1,h-1).

Comment: as it to be an `Array` or could you use `Matrix`?

Comment: @WiiMaxx: I could use a Matrix. I'm just reading and writing to X,Y coords. I didn't know .NET had a Matrix class. What method would you use to pull out a region?

Comment: @Mark i think [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3354/Efficient-Matrix-Programming-in-C) you get all you need

Comment: @WiiMaxx: Seems a bit overkill for my needs. I'm not going to add a 3rd party matrix lib just to pull out a subsection of an array in a project that doesn't otherwise need matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx):

```
int w2 = x2 - x1 + 1;
int h2 = y2 - y1 + 1;
byte[,] array2 = new byte[w2, h2];
for (int i = 0; i < w2; i++)
{
    Array.Copy(array1, (i+x1)*h + y1, array2, i*h2, h2);
}
```

This might be faster for large arrays. The two nested loops are however more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I cant come up with a faster way, but you could use two nested loops:

```
byte[,] array2 = new byte[x2 - x1, y2 - y1];
for (int i = x1; i < x2; i++)
{
    for (int j = y1; j < y2; j++)
    {
        array2[i-x1, j-y1] = array[i, j];
    }
}
```

For a jagged array you could use a linq query:

```
IEnumerable<byte> x = array3.Skip(x1)
                            .Take(x2-x1)
                            .SelectMany(a => a.Skip(y1).Take(y2-y1));
```

Comment: Thought maybe we could use some kind of MemoryStream to copy chunks at at time. Oh well, this will have to do for now. Thanks :-)

Comment: Yep, I suspect there is.  I hope this isn't the best answer.